# Как сравнить элементы списка и словаря. Найти сумму списка со значениями из словаря

Tags: python, условия

Суть: есть словарь, где каждому элементу (продукту) присваивается цена
Задача: посчитать общую стоимость продуктов, которые внесены в список nourriture
Проблема: если в список внести 2 одинаковых элемента из словаря (например ["pomme", "orange", "orange"], то одинаковые элементы считаются 1 раз, а не 2 (например, для ["pomme", "orange", "orange"] должен общую сумму вернуть 5, а возвращает 3,5).
Как тогда прописать условие?

```
prix = { "banane": 4,
    "pomme": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "poire": 3
}

def calculer_facture(nourriture):
    total = 0
    for produit in prix:
        if produit in nourriture:
            total = total + prix[produit]
    return total
```

Answer (score 2):

Как то так:

```
>>> prix = {"banane": 4, "pomme": 2, "orange": 1.5, "poire": 3}
>>> nourriture = ["pomme", "orange", "orange"]
>>> sum(prix[n] for n in nourriture)
5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prix = {"banane": 4, "pomme": 2, "orange": 1.5, "poire": 3}

def calculer_facture(nourriture):
    total = 0
    for produit in prix:
        if produit in nourriture:
            total += prix[produit] * nourriture.count(produit)
    return total
```